# Can I somehow set the tower shield down as cover?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, shield, cover

Is it possible to set a tower shield in a place to gain cover but without the the need to hold it with one arm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No, you cannot

There are no feats or archetype abilities that allow you to gain the benefits of a tower shield without actually holding it. All abilities that allow you to gain AC/cover benefits from a tower shield require you to be holding it.

### But you can benefit from it if it's animated

[Animated](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicArmorDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Animated) tower shields can be "dropped" and still provide all of its bonuses to its owner:

> As a move action, an animated shield can be loosed to defend its wielder on its own. For the following 4 rounds, the shield grants its bonus to the one who loosed it and then drops. While animated, the shield provides **its shield bonus and the bonuses from all of the other shield special abilities** it possesses

There are also other magic items that have similar behavior, such as the [Battlement Shield](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicArmorDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Battlement%20Shield):

> Once per day on command, this +2 tower shield can transform into a solid, 1-foot-thick, 10-foot-by-10-foot wall of masonry with a battlement on top and an arrow slit in each 5-foot length. The wall acts as cover just like any physical wall.

Or [Fortress Shield](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicArmorDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Fortress%20Shield):

> The wearer of this +1 tower shield may, as a full-round action, transform the shield into a 1-inch-thick cube of iron that springs into being around him, completely enclosing his space.

Comment: I feel like "shield special abilities" has more to do with magical abilities, but it would be silly not to allow this. Good thinking.

Comment: There are homebrew 5e rules for pavises: https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Pavise_(5e_Equipment). Shouldn't be hard to adapt them to Pathfinder.